# How many terms are 'missing'?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, indeterminate-forms

I know in this particular indeterminate partial sum S = $3^n - 3^{n+1} + 3^{n+2} - 3^{n+3} + \cdots + 3^{3n}$ where $a=3^n$ and $r=-3$. So I know if $3^1$ were the first term, there would be $3n$ terms. But I am missing $3^1,3^2,3^3, \cdots , 3^{n-1}$ (namely $n-1$ terms). Therefore $3n-(n-1) = 2n+1$ terms.

Now here's what I am having trouble with trying to apply the same process and find how many terms there are missing of this

$3^k + 3^{k-1} + 3^{k-2} + \cdots + 3^{-2k}$

it's hard to me now because it's counting down by 1. I believe that if $3^1$ was the first term there would be $-2k$ terms. But how do you find how many terms come before that? I was thinking like $3^{k+1 -1}$ comes before $3^k$ but am having trouble expanding the expression to make it clear to me what's happening to find how many terms are missing to get the number of terms there are. Also don't exactly know what the common ratio is but I see that the sign doesn't alternate so must have a positive value of r.

Basically, I  want to apply the process used in the $3^n$ expression to that of the $3^k$ expression. Please help

Answer (score 0):

An idea: write

$$3^n-3^{n+1}+\ldots+3^{3n}=3^n\left(1-3+3^2-3^3+\ldots+3^{2n}\right)=3^n\sum_{k=0}^{2n}3^k$$

Comment: was hoping to write the 3^k question that was addressed

Comment: i would get $3^{-k}$ terms?

Comment: @randomvalue That's not even a natural number for $\;k:0\;$ ...!

Comment: yeah what u wrote confused the hell out of me. Would it be 3n-3k terms? i need to see the same process i used applied to the sum involving k

Comment: $3^{n-1}$ terms comes before $3^n$ so what comes before $3^k$ in the case that it's decremented by 1 each time not incremented

Comment: @randomvalue Do $2-3$ examples so that you'll understand. For example, if $\;n=4\;$, then you have the terms $\;3^4-3^5+\ldots+3^{12}\;$ . How many terms do you have here? Yes, exactly $\;9=12-4+1 ...$

Comment: ok i understand your idea but i still was more addressing the question that's decremented each time. What would be to the left of $3^k + 3^{k-1} \cdots +3^{-2k}$ How many terms are missing to the left and therefore there are how many terms?

Comment: @randomvalue It's the very same case! Why the minus sign would change anything?! Again, do examples...with $\;k=3\;$ , for example...

Comment: I don’t think you understand why I’m confused though. Where I’m coming from is this. $3^{n-1} Then \, 3^{n-1+1}= 3^n$. Now the subtract situation from left to right. $3^{k+1} Then \, 3^{k+1-1} = 3^k$? That is the same thing? So that means ur missing k+1 terms or k-1 terms?